# Проблема с телеграм-ботом (Python, Telebot)

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

Идея бота:
В небольшой группе в телеграм будет несколько пользователей из трех стран и бот. Пользователь пишет сообщение на любом из трёх языков - русский, английский, турецкий. В ответ получает клавиатуру с выбором трёх языков. Выбирает свой язык, после чего получает в ответ сообщение на своём языке + его же переведенное на остальные два языка.
(кому интересно, как буду осуществлять перевод, могу поделиться, из кода методы убрал, но они работают отлично, с ними ник проблема не связана. Я долго подбирал переводчик с бесплатным API, но в итоге придумал своё решение. А также отказался от идеи анализа языка написанного сообщения, в пользу нажатия кнопочки, потому что не придумал идеальный алгоритм,  который безошибочно определял бы язык сообщения, без использования нейросети. Встроенная в питоне библиотека работала некорректно.)

Итак, что работает на данный момент.

1. При запуске бота он отправляет сообщение "бот запущен"
2. Пользователь вводит сообщение
3. В ответ на это приходит сообщение "выберите язык"
4. Пользователь выбирает язык, выбранный язык пишется в чат
5. В ответ на это бот снова присылает "выберите язык" и так до бесконечности может продолжаться

т.е. он не воспринимает отправленное ему сообщение и никак не обрабатывает его с последующей отправкой.
Помогите, пожалуйста, чем это можно пофиксить? Что я не учёл? Бота пишу впервые

```
import telebot

# Ключи, токены и id

   
BOT_TOKEN = "Цензура:)"
chat_id = Цензура:)

# Устанавливаем токен бота
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)

# Словарь для хранения выбранного языка для каждого чата
language_dict = {}

# Метод для перевода текста
def translate_russian(message):
    translation = "Текст на русском, английском и турецком языках."
    return translation

def translate_english(message):
    translation = "Text in English, Russian, and Turkish languages."
    return translation

def translate_turkish(message):
    translation = "Türkçe, İngilizce ve Rusça dillerinde metin."
    return translation

# Обработчик команды /start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Бот запущен. Пожалуйста, напишите сообщение.")

# Обработчик текстовых сообщений
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def text_message(message):
    # Проверяем, был ли выбран язык для текущего чата
    if message.chat.id in language_dict:
        # Если язык выбран, переходим к отправке соответствующего метода
        send_method(message)
    else:
        # Если язык не выбран, отправляем сообщение с просьбой выбрать язык
        bot.reply_to(message, "Выберите язык.", reply_markup=generate_language_keyboard())

# Генерируем клавиатуру с кнопками выбора языка
def generate_language_keyboard():
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add("Русский", "Английский", "Турецкий")
    return keyboard

# Обработчик выбора русского языка
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'русский')
def choose_russian(message):
    language_dict[message.chat.id] = 'русский'
    bot.reply_to(message, "Выбран язык: русский")
    send_method(message)

# Обработчик выбора английского языка
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'английский')
def choose_english(message):
    language_dict[message.chat.id] = 'английский'
    bot.reply_to(message, "Выбран язык: английский")
    send_method(message)

# Обработчик выбора турецкого языка
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'турецкий')
def choose_turkish(message):
    language_dict[message.chat.id] = 'турецкий'
    bot.reply_to(message, "Выбран язык: турецкий")
    send_method(message)

# Метод для отправки соответствующего метода перевода
def send_method(message):
    # Получаем выбранный язык для текущего чата
    language = language_dict[message.chat.id]

    # Получаем текст сообщения от пользователя
    message_text = message.text

    # Выбираем соответствующий метод перевода
    if language == "русский":
        translation = translate_russian(message_text)
    elif language == "английский":
        translation = translate_english(message_text)
    elif language == "турецкий":
        translation = translate_turkish(message_text)

    # Отправляем перевод пользователю
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Перевод:\n{translation}")


# Запускаем бота
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Бот запущен. Пожалуйста, напишите сообщение.")
    bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем коде допущена серьёзная ошибка последовательности `message_handler`'ов и работы с глобальной переменной `language_dict`, а так же косяки работы с `ReplyKeyboard`.

---

**Первое** на что стоит обратить внимание, это вот это недоразумение:

```
... # здесь какой-то код
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'русский')
...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'английский')
...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'турецкий')
...
```

Когда приходит сообщение, он прогоняет все хандлеры по порядку, измените порядок таким образом:

```
... # здесь какой-то код
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'русский')
...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'английский')
...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() == 'турецкий')
...
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
...
```

В результате сначала будут проверяться хандлеры на конкретные слова, а затем на любое другое слово.

---

**Второе** - неправильное использование глобальных переменных. Если вы хотите узнать/изменить значение из глобальной переменной, используйте тэг `global` везде где вы хотите обращаться к глобальной переменной. На примере хандлера на любое сообщение:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def text_message(message):
    global language_dict
    ...
```

---

**Третье** (но больше имхо) - когда язык уже был выбран, по хорошему считается удаление `ReplyKeyboard`, данное можно реализовать с помощью `reply_markup=telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()`. На примере отправки сообщения с параметром `русский`:

```
bot.reply_to(message, "Выбран язык: русский", reply_markup=telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
```

p.s. по хорошему реализовать в таком случае отдельную инструкцию для выбора языка

---

Поведение в результате правок кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

p.s.2 По хорошему в моменте запуска бота сразу показывать клавиатуру и отправлять инструкции что как и зачем

p.s.3 Если вы собирайтесь реализовать данного бота как сервис, избавьтесь от `chat_id` и используйте просто токен, пускай ваш бот активизируется путем использования `/start`, это разрешит пользователю сделать "первый шаг", ежели этот "шаг" будет делать бот, имхо

Comment: Очень помогли, даже с тем, что я планировал исправлять позже, большое спасибо!
С клавиатурой хорошее замечание, но там есть люди, которые пишут на двух языках и для них клавиатуру нужно оставить. Буду разбираться)